# Visual Studio 2010 expanding all database tables for no reason

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide

so I'm working on an mvc2 project with visual studio. I have 5 or 6 data connections in my server explorer tab which is pinned. All of a sudden a strange error pops up that has nothing to do with what I'm currently doing in visual studio.

[image]

I then open the server explorer pane and all my data connections are now connected. One of the connections then has every table in the tree expanded. It's pretty annoying and I don't know what is causing it or how to make it stop.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about expanding and collapsing issue, but that error has to do with not having the Diagramming functionality set up on the Database being referenced

Comment: funny thing is i'm not trying to view the diagram. Since the "Database Diagram" node probably tries to be expanded or something that error probably pops up.

Comment: @Steve - visual studio might be trying to "help" by making some assumptions about the structure of the database.. I bet there's a setting somewhere that toggles that behavior, which would probably help in getting some more helpful answers